# Facebook is not showing my link images or info

Tags: facebook, wordpress, hyperlink, translate

I am using wordpress for my blog I also added it in spanish but when I share the link on Facebook it  does not show any images just the link info how can I fix this?

I went on Facebook debug and it says: The 'og:url' property is required, but not present. 
the link im using is www.zabiknowsitall.com/es

Comment: You've got a problem with your server. For non-browsers, your site is throwing `500: Internal Server Errors`. Take a look at the `Response Code` section of the Facebook Debugger screen.

Comment: This question might be better asked (and answered) on [ServerFault.com](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the image meta tag too.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://zabiknowsitall.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cropped-header1.png" />
```

I've found Facebook to cache pages quite aggressively so you may need to wait a while for it to update.

The reason why Facebook can't read the og meta at all though is due to your server returning an HTTP status code of 500 (Server Error). It should be returning a 200, so you'll need to explore why this happening.

A handy tool for testing opengraph can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fzabiknowsitall.com%2Fes

Comment: Sorry.. I am kind of new to this... where should I add the meta tag.. do you think that would make a change?

Comment: In the html head with the others. Are the others added with a plugin?

The important thing to solve is why the page is returning an error 500. This will stop Facebook from reading any of the page details

Comment: not sure.. I will try to see if I can fix it.. not very smart about coding and things like that.

Comment: its weird because when i use www.zabiknowsitall.com it works perfectly fine but the problem is with www.zabiknowsitall.com/es I was using WPML so I am guessing that's what the problem is... not sure why it does not recognized it... but the site can still be accessed

Comment: I noticed that it only happens on the Spanish version. Do you use any different plugins or themes on the Spanish one which aren't on the other?